# ReSharper 9.2 "Go to Implementation" not working for inherited generic interfaces

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-9.0

I'm using ReSharper 9.2 (stuck with this version for now) and I have a case, rather common one for us, where "Go to implementation" doesn't work. Even worse, you'd think that there really is no implementation.

This is an example for this behavior:

```
public interface ITest<in TFrom, out TTo>
{
    TTo SomeMethod(TFrom inp);
}

public interface ISpecialTest : ITest<string, int>
{
    void AnotherMethod();
}

public class Implementation : ISpecialTest
{
    public int SomeMethod(string inp)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public void AnotherMethod()
    {
    }
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
     ISpecialTest t = new Implementation();
     t.SomeMethod("test"); // Resharper"Go to implementation" does NOT work
     t.AnotherMethod(); // Resharper"Go to implementation" DOES work
}
```

Does anybody experience the same behavior and might have a clue if this is fixed in a new version, or even better, fix it somehow in version 9.2 of Resharper?

Comment: Same behavior in Resharper 10.0.1. It goes to `TTo SomeMethod(TFrom inp);`

Comment: Hmm.. That's also strange. When using "Go to **Implementation**"? Because that's the interface definition where it goes to, not an implementation at all.

Comment: Found the same behavior.