# "Go to implementation" on interface with ReSharper

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper, shortcut

I have the following usual code construct with an interface, an implementing class and a call to the interface method.

```
public class ImplementingClass : IInterface
{
  public void Method<T>() {}
}

public interface IInterface()
{
  void Method<T>();
}

public class CallingClass()
{
  private void CallingMethod()
  {
    IInterface instance = new ImplementingClass();
    instance.Method<object>();
  }
}
```

From [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21461161/1843468) I learned that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click means "go to declaration" (i. e. the interface) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Click means "go to implementation" in ReSharper.

When I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click on `Method` in `instance.Method();`, it takes me to `IInterface.Method`. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click on that declaration again does nothing - so far as expected.

**But**: if I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Click on `instance.Method();`, it still takes me to `IInterface.Method`, and only the second <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Click takes me to `ImplementingClass.Method`.

Is that a setting problem in ReSharper, a shortcut interference with Visual Studio Professional 2015, a misunderstanding of what "implementation" means in this context, or is it simply a bug in ReSharper 9.2?

N. B.: "Go to implementation" from the context menu of `instance.Method();` takes me directly to `ImplementingClass.Method`, and there is only one implementation of that interface.

The interface itself has no generics and is not inherited, but the method has a generic (as shown above). It could possibly be related to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33911538/resharper-9-2-go-to-implementation-not-working-for-inherited-generic-interface), although my setup is not quite as complex as over there.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a bug in ReSharper 9.2. I tried it in 10.0.2, and it looks like it's completely broken - Ctrl+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Click does nothing, while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+Click just shows the context menu. I've raised an issue: [RSRP-452834](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-452834).